# Sending broadcast with Chrome Extensions

Tags: networking, google-chrome-extension, distributed-caching, google-nativeclient

I'm coding an **extension** for a customer, one of the requirements is that the extension also works offline because **internet services are not that reliable**, my customer's business can't stop but can deal with "stale" data, thats a nice tradeoff I guess.

Therefore, I want to code some kind of **distributed cache** as an extension to synchronize local data among the N nodes that will be connected running the same application and thus synchronize with the real database, hosted on the internet.

In order to achieve that I imagined that I would need to make a **network broadcast** and listen to incoming broadcasts, then every node that starts to run my application will broadcast it's IP address and become available as a new node for the **distributed cache**, failover is very important here.

I googled some possibilities I initially thought but none of them will work, I guess. The first was to do it just with **HTTP**, the second was to use **Google Native Client** to write **C++** code that could run network code and thus do the **broadcast**, but it has limitations. Right now I'm thinking to use **Java Applets** but I don't really know if they have some limitations related to networking or if **Chrome Extensions** has any limitation with **Java Applets**.

Any ideas on how to do it? Using some of the stuff I suggested or another approach?

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing what kind of data you need to hang on to.  What exactly do you need to accomplish while offline?  What data are you caching?  What are you doing with that data?

Comment: Brad, thanks for your answer! I would like to store some events like an order made by a customer, that order must be available to the cheff and also to the cashier. I think events will be simple messages, think of a restaurant app, it could send what product is being requested, the table asking it, the waiter serving the customer, etc.

Comment: Why not just have a server running locally, that syncs up over the web when necessary?

Comment: Because I want to provide it as a service, the maximum intrusive I want to be is to ask my customer to install a Chrome Extension.

Comment: You are not allowed to do that from JavaScript or C++ in Chrome. Java Applet should work though.

Comment: Why does it have to be so complicated?  Why not just have an offline and online mode?  While offline the information would be saved in LocalStorage.  When a network connection is available, sync with the server.

Comment: The problem is not to store data as I said, the problem is that I need to propagate data offline without a server.

Comment: Chrome does not really like Java. You must have seen those "java plugin-in needs your permission to run" bars...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an [NPAPI extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html), which would not be restricted by Chrome at all.